# Ouput to text file using C++ STL library in Android

Tags: android, c++, stl, java-native-interface

I have an Android application that use JNI. In JNI I used C++ STL library to output some data into a text file. 
This is the snippet code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

float mydata[4] = {0.0f};

ofstream file;
file.open("Data.txt", ios::app);

// For example
file<<mydata[1];

file.close();
```

when I ran ndk-build, I did not face any errors and the program seems run properly. But I did not found any text file in my Application directory. 
does anybody know what could be the issue? Please help.

Thanks

Comment: What is `Data.txt`? It must be a string literal: `"Data.txt"`. It's weird that you don't face any compilation errors (unless there is an object named `Data` with a string field `txt`).

Comment: You can also check outpuf of `getcwd()` (from `unistd.h`) to be sure what directory the program is running in.

Comment: Hi EarGray, Sorry I've edited the post. So do you know what's wrong here?

Comment: Try to use checks for opening errors (like `if (!file) { ...` after `file.open()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works, but you apparently try to access a path which is forbidden.

- Firstly, be sure that your Android application asks for storage permissions.
- Secondly, try to replace `"Data"` by an absolute path you know you have access to (e.g. `"/sdcard/Pictures/Data.txt"`).

Also, as a better practice, you should test if the file has been opened before writing to it.

Comment: Hi, Oh I see. I did not have sdcard, so where could be the best place to store the data?

Comment: You don't need to have an external memory card, if it is what you mean. But you should have the `"/sdcard/"` directory anyway. Try to connect to your phone by plugging it to your computer and run `adb shell`. Then you'll be able to see the folders and to find the location where you want to save your file.